# Setting up google oauth for Airflow 2 Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch

Tags: airflow, google-oauth, airflow-2.x

Steps I've taken:

I created a new project in google cloud under OAuth 2.0 Client IDs. Under `Authorised redirect URIs` I've added our Airflow url (along with other ones because none of them seem to work):

```
https://airflow-something.net/home/
https://airflow-something.net/home
https://airflow-something.net/
```

I added this webserver_config.py file to my Airflow home dir:

```
from flask_appbuilder.security.manager import AUTH_OAUTH
import os
from airflow.models import Variable
import logging

basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

AUTH_TYPE = AUTH_OAUTH
AUTH_ROLES_SYNC_AT_LOGIN = True 
AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION = True 
AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION_ROLE = "Admin"


OAUTH_PROVIDERS = [
    {
        "name": "google",
        "icon": "fa-google",
        "token_key": "access_token",
        "whitelist": ['@meowmeow.com'],
        "remote_app": {
            "client_id": os.getenv("CLIENT_ID"),
            "client_secret": os.getenv("CLIENT_SECRET"),
            "api_base_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/",
            "client_kwargs": {"scope": "email profile"},
            "access_token_url": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
            "authorize_url": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
            "request_token_url": None,

        },
    },
]
```

The error I see is:

> Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch. Request details:
> redirect_uri=https://airflow-something.net/oauth-authorized/google

Also if I add that URL to the `Authorised redirect URIs` in GCP and I go to the Airflow link, it just keeps logging me in and logging me out.

Comment: you need to add the redirect uri in the project where you created that client id, it needs to match exactly

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo are you referring to the Authorised redirect URIs in the google UI? I've added examples above of the urls I've added there. I've also added some urls under Authorised JavaScript origins. Or did you mean something else?

Comment: Try this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QHz1Rs6lZHQ

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo - thanks! This was a great video! Unfortunately, I now see this error: 
Error authorizing OAuth access token: misma[REDACTED]: CSRF Warning! State not equal in request and response.